# Segmentation fault on auto-complete

Tags: front-end, bugs, autocomplete

My front-end freezes as soon as I type more than two letters in a notebook. I think the error occurs, when the auto-complete feature kicks in. If Mathematica was started from a terminal, the following text is shown.

```
Mathematica has received the signal: SIGSEGV and has exited.
If possible, please report this problem to support@wolfram.com
describing in as much detail as possible what you were doing
when the problem occurred.
```

I use Mathematica 10.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. Rebooting and `-cleanstart` did not help. This installation worked fine for quite some time, but suddenly this problem appeared.

Is this a known problem? Before I contact the official support, I want to make sure that there is no trivial fix.

Comment: @StefanR You were right, `CodeAssistHistory10.3.m` was 321MB big! Removed it, everything works. Thanks!

Comment: @murphy good to hear! Sorry you ran into this!

Comment: @StefanR Maybe you should add your comment as an answer. That would make it more future-proof and I could close the question.

Comment: I have just noted a similar behavior on **10.4** (Win 10 Pro), where all text  inputs after two characters suddenly stopped as can bee seen in this [capture of the problem](http://imgur.com/w6jqbUp). Unfortunately I was pointed to this post too late - I am just reinstalling Mathematica...

Comment: See also [**this post**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/295310#_19_message_785691) asking for bug reports including the `CodeAssistHistory` files for better diagnostics of this problem and hopefully a fix in the future.

Comment: By the way, the issue also appears on Mathematica 10.4 with Windows 7. And, I also noticed that whenever I type 3 letters to let this happen, the memory usage of Mathematica increases by a lot. I can then keep doing this such that it uses up all the memory I have.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(Posting my comment as an answer, per @murphy's suggestion)

Please check the folder

`$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/Functional‌​Frequency`

and see if there are any unusually large files there (>100 Kb or so). If any such files exist, please delete them. The file `CodeAssistHistory10.3.m` is often the culprit, and is safe to delete.

Comment: Are there plans to fix this?  My `CodeAssistHistory10.4.m` is also huge (25.2 MB), and most of it is just a bunch of `ÂÃÂÃ`...

Comment: @QuantumDot we believe we have a fix for this in Mathematica 10.4.1.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works with regard to my above comment. My `CodeAssistHistory10.4m` had a size of 712 MB at the time of deletion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! My file was 1.5GB in size at the time of deletion!

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I didn't have any files of the form `Code*` in my FunctionalFrequency folder, and none of the files were over 18 MB.  I deleted all the ones over 100 KB but the problem still persists if I enable autocomplete.

Comment: @StephanR Deleting all the files of the form *.m didn't work either.

Comment: @tparker are you using _Mathematica_ 10.4.1, or an earlier version?

Comment: @StefanR Sorry, I should have specified.  I was using Mathematica 10.3 (.8, I believe) when I left my comment.  I have since updated to version 10.4.1 and now it's working again.

Comment: @StefanR I just upgraded to Mathematica 10.4.1 and am still facing this issue. I don't have any file named CodeAssistHistory*.m, but I do have many large (> 1 MB) *.trie files and also SystemFunctionTemplates.nb. Are those okay to delete?

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast Please do not delete any files other than the ones in `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/Functional‌​Frequency` that are named `CodeAssistHistory*.m`. Deleting anything else might corrupt your _Mathematica_ installation. Do you have a large `CodeAssistHistory10.4.1.m` file, by any chance?

Comment: @StefanR Thanks for the response. I was actually able to solve the issue earlier; after disabling auto-correct, I was able to use _Mathematica_ to find that `$UserBaseDirectory` on Windows is hidden and is `.../AppData/Roaming/Mathematica`, not the path where I was originally looking. Once I navigated to the correct directory, I was able to find a very large (~ 1 GB) `CodeAssistHistory10.4.m`, which I deleted. Subsequently turning on auto-complete has given me no problems since.

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast Ok, good to know! If you run into this in the future, it would be of help to us if you could zip the offending `CodeAssistHistory` file and send it to us.

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast One more question: Did you start to see the crashes in 10.4.0 or 10.4.1?

Comment: @StefanR In 10.4.0. I'm assuming that the problem persisted in 10.4.1 because `CodeAssistHistory10.4.m` was still present (and, of course, very large).

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast Thanks! We're still trying to verify that our fix in 10.4.1 stops the `CodeAssistHistory` file from blowing up in the first place, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem when the file is already corrupted.