# Mathematica crashing when attempting autocompletion

Tags: crash, autocomplete, ubuntu

I have been using *Mathematica* 10.4 Student Edition since months and it worked just fine on my Asus X552C (Ubuntu 14.04). Three or four days ago the problem started. Whenever I try to type something into a notebook, it freezes. I have noticed that it happens during autocompletion. For example, if I type "Si" with the intention of writing "Simplify", it freezes for a few minutes and takes down the whole computer! It seemed to be coming back to normal until yesterday, when it got worse. *Mathematica* just crashes after freezing for a few moments. It kept doing this and I was unable to work at all, so I unistalled it and re-installed the earlier version 10.2, but the problem persists. I am clueless about what to do. I desperately need a solution because I am up against a deadline.

Comment: You should contact Wolfram Support for this issue.  It is out of scope of the help available here.

Comment: You can turn off autocompletion in the preferences pane.

Comment: Had the same problem.  Found the solution here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109005/segmentation-fault-on-auto-complete/109319#109319

Comment: @QuantumDot I did exactly that, turned off the autocompletion and it's back to normal. Thanks. I will also check that link now Luis..