# Mathematica crashes during auto-complete on Mac OS X

Tags: crash, mac-os-x, autocomplete

Mathematica crashes when I type in a few characters. This has been addressed and solved before on the forum. The answer is that a very large file has been created, and once you delete it, the problem is solved.

However, I am running Mathematica 10.2.0.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1421) and the file and its path are specified for Ubuntu and Windows. I can't find the file by either following the path or using "Spotlight".

The file is apparently called "CodeAssistHistory10.3.m", at least on other operating systems. A link to the prior discussion is

[Segmentation fault on auto-complete](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109005/segmentation-fault-on-auto-complete?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Does anybody know where I can find this errant file?

Comment: You should look in this folder: `~/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/FunctionalFrequency/`. Note that `Library` folder is usually hidden in OS X. To get there use Finder's menu `Go to` and press shift key to see `Library`.

Comment: I have been getting the Spinning ball on Mac OS X 10.9.5 again since installing to 11.1 when inserting the cursor into something as an empty or new cell. I will also try this to see if it fixes. The problem went away in one of the 11.0x releases ... but now it is back.

Comment: Shadowray - Thank you. It didn't occur to me that Mathematica would dynamically change $UserBaseDirectory, or that files in this directory would be invisible to Spotlight. Anyway, yes, I looked there, found the file, and deleted the >250MB CodeAssist file that I found there. All is good now.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X the `CodeAssistHistory` files are stored in the following folder:

`~/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/FunctionalFrequency/`

Note that `Library` folder is usually hidden from Finder and Spotlight in OS X. To get there use Finder's menu `Go to` and press shift key to see `Library` option.