# Mathematica 11.3 crashing on either startup or after typing in a notebook

Tags: front-end, crash

I have been having an issue with my Mathematica 11.3 installation. Often after running a notebook for a long time, my Mathematica will crash suddenly for strange reasons like just typing in the notebook.

Upon starting up the program, the same simple operations such as typing will cause Mathematica to crash.

The only good solution I have found has been to restart my PC. Even uninstalling and reinstalling Mathematica does not seem to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. It may be better to email Wolfram Support about your particular issue, since they might have more advanced debugging methods than we do. In any case, it would be helpful if you could add your operating system to your question and perhaps the specs of your computer. If you nail down some reproduction steps, that's probably also quite useful (no matter who you're talking to :) )

Comment: I don't see how we can help you with your problem without a better description of the nature of the crashes you are experiencing. Here are some of the things that would be useful to know. 1) what OS are you running? 2) When you say "crash", do you mean kernel crash or front-end crash? 3) If it is the front-end that is crashing, what are the symptoms -- lock-up of the front-end evaluator or killing of the front-end process by OS? When and if you provide answers to these questions, please do not make them comments: edit your question.

Comment: Refer to http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464, reset it to its default configuration and try again.

Comment: Had the same problem.  Found the solution here: 
   [Segmentation fault on auto-complete](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109005/segmentation-fault-on-auto-complete)