# Mathematica 10.4 freezes and stops after a few keystrokes

Tags: bugs, crash

I have found out today that whenever I open a Mathematica notebook and type in no more than two characters, the notebook freezes and abruptly closes. I do not know how to resolve this. There is a similar discussion like this, but for a Windows machine. Does anyone know how to fix this on Ubuntu? I do not wish to reinstall Mathematica.

Comment: Does this work: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109005/38205?

Comment: I'm not sure how to locate the base directory.

Comment: Evaluate `$UserBaseDirectory`

Comment: I found it via the terminal and the codeassist file was there. I'll check its size and delete it. But the point is I could not type the command on Mathematica since it crashes just after typing two/three characters.

Comment: Seems to be working now. Thanks for the suggestion!